# Apparmor Init Failed, Exit Code 123

Tags: boot, security, 16.04, systemd, apparmor

Apparmor fails boot and command line start with same result as below

```
x@x-NICEPUTER:~$ systemctl --failed
  UNIT             LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● apparmor.service loaded failed failed LSB: AppArmor initialization

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.

x@x-NICEPUTER:~$ systemctl status apparmor.service
● apparmor.service - LSB: AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apparmor; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-05-03 21:52:29 MDT; 1h 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 523 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=123)

May 03 21:52:22 x-NICEPUTER apparmor[523]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.webbrowser-app in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.webbrowser-app at line 26: Could not open '/usr/share/apparmor/hardware/graphics.d'
May 03 21:52:28 x-NICEPUTER apparmor[523]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER apparmor[523]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER apparmor[523]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.webbrowser-app in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.webbrowser-app at line 26: Could not open '/usr/share/apparmor/hardware/graphics.d'
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER apparmor[523]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER apparmor[523]:    ...fail!
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=123
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 03 21:52:29 x-NICEPUTER systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Directories `apparmor/hardware/` and file `graphics.d` do not exist inside  `/usr/share/`
Thus `#include /usr/share/apparmor/hardware/graphics.d` at line 26 of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.webbrowser-app` returns null and causes the failure.

How can I properly fix this or at the least create a workaround that allows `apparmor.service` to intialize without a failure?

```
uname -a
Linux x-NICEPUTER 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sudo lshw
[sudo] password for x: 
x-niceputer               
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3793MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8400  @ 2.26GHz
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems to be a reported bug ([#1554803](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1554803))

It can be solved installing `apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu` or creating the folders by hand.

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer and providing the proper steps to install the package you are referring to or to create the necessary folders.  I looked at the bug it is indeed the same I see.  Thank you :)

Comment: how this solving this problem ?

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT I don't think this solves the AppArmor problem but provides a way to keep systemd from failing AppArmor initialization on boot. I built the folders and empty files by hand and, I ran the installation of apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu. Files (video.d, graphics.d, and audio.d) are still empty in my system and boot no longer records a fail code. These files are supposed to contain AppArmor policy code, I think, its a guess based on first line here https://launchpad.net/apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu  Not sure if Apparmor protects these devices? Bug still open!

Comment: For me, I was unable to install any package because `ifconfig` and `network-manager` would not load (I have a USB wifi dongle). So @xtrchessreal 's suggestion is what worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem appeared when I uninstalled the snapd package with `apt-get remove snapd`. Checking the syslog, it seems the snapd uninstaller deleted some directories but not the apparmor config files referencing them. I pruned the package with `apt-get purge snapd` and restarted apparmor without errors.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I couldn't install any packages because both `ifconfig` and `network-manager` could not find/start my USB wifi dongle.

So @xtrchessreal's [comment is what worked for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767272/apparmor-init-failed-exit-code-123#comment1418362_767686):

In the recovery mode shell, create the following directories:

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/apparmor/hardware/graphics.d
mkdir -p /usr/share/apparmor/hardware/audio.d
mkdir -p /usr/share/apparmor/hardware/video.d
```

And then `reboot`

Comment: apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu IMPORTANT: this project is no longer actively maintained by the Ubuntu Security team of Canonical. Per https://launchpad.net/apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu  I wonder if it maintained elsewhere?

Comment: Good to know! I'm just going to remove it from the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :go to advanced options for
ubuntu

Step 2: start with Linux 4.4. 0-22
generic (recovery mode)

Step 3: then click (dpkg) from the list

Step 4: Wait for a moment, then it is
not working type ' sudo-install-(next vesion) 16.04 of ubuntu
Then wait for few minutes

Step 5: then resume and resart