# Blank screen post BIOS after using apt-get -f install

Tags: boot, apt

#### System Info:

- Dell Inspiron 1318
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, single boot

#### System doesn't boot past BIOS:

My Ubuntu laptop was working like a charm until I hit a snag. I was trying to install a package using `dpkg -i`, when it prompted me that some dependencies are required and it recommended to run `apt-get -f install`.

I ran that and during the installation, I got a pop-up (which filled the entire screen) saying a reboot would be required, with `<OK>` button. So I restarted the computer and now I get a black screen after BIOS.

Searching around, I tried hitting the `Shift` key several times which gave me the Grub menu with:

- *Ubuntu
- *Advanced options for Ubuntu

I selected 'Advanced options...' after which I get more options, and I selected the second one ...0-98-generic (recovery mode):

[image]

Then I get the following:

[image]

I am having terminal access to everything using `root`. Not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Here are screenshots after running `journalctl -xb`. I am not sure if there is a better way to show this information, since it gives me a long list of lines.

[image]

---

#### Update 1:

I tried reinstalling Ubuntu hoping that it would repair the installation. I made a LiveUSB with Ubuntu and inserted it in the machine and selected Boot from USB Storage Device and I just get a Black screen with a blinking cursor, it isn't moving to the 'Try Ubuntu', 'Install Ubuntu' page.

I also tried fixing the AppArmor issue, by trying to install `apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu` as given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767272/apparmor-init-failed-exit-code-123). But I am not able to connect to the internet, hence can't download using `apt-get`.

---

#### Update 2:

I connected an ethernet cable and set-up wired internet and was able to fix the AppArmor issue by downloading and installing `apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu`. I also ran `apt-get {update, upgrade, dist-upgrade}` while in recovery mode. Now I NO longer get the 'Failed to start LSB' error, however I still get this error:

- `Dependency failed for /dev/disk...`
- `Dependency failed for Swap`

And when I boot I only get terminal access, can't see login screen.

---

#### Update 3:

Here are the contents of the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=02f386fb-70ab-43d0-998c-8a30209872f5   /  ext4  errors=remount-ro 0  1
UUID=ab53ebf0-4ab5-49eb-ad80-31cb46a69724 none swap  sw                0  0
```

And here are the results after running `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="02f386fb-70ab-43d0-998c-8a30209872f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bebca47d-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="ab53ebf0-4ab5-49eb-ad80-31cb46a69724" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="bebca47d-05"
```

Comment: Can you boot in recovery mode?

Comment: The screenshot is after booting in recovery mode. It gives me terminal access.

Comment: Can you post the output of running `journalctl -xb`?

Comment: It shows me a long list of lines in the terminal. Any ideas how I can share it here?

Comment: I guess for your convenience you can just take a picture as you have done before...

Comment: @NerdOfCode I added a screenshot after running `journalctl -xb`. Not sure how helpful it is.

Comment: Not too sure...so to be clear what happens when you boot normally?

Comment: @NerdOfCode I just get a black screen. I am going to attempt reinstalling Ubuntu. Previously I had removed some packages manually, which may have broken some driver. Hopefully a reinstall may be the way to go.

Comment: How did the reinstall go?

Comment: @NerdOfCode Didn't go well :( See Update 1. After I put my LiveUSB, it is stuck on a black screen with blinking cursor. I don't get past it.

Comment: Can you access an Ethernet connection to fix `apparmor`?

Comment: @NerdOfCode see Update 2. I fixed the apparmor issue (some progress), but I am getting the Dependency failed..` error.

Comment: What happens if you boot to older kernel, e.g. 4.4.0-97?

Comment: @dimm same regardless of which kernel I select.

Comment: Whatever you installed that made this mess, can you unistall it from the recovery console including with all its dependencies. `sudo apt autoremove <packagename>`

Comment: The TexStudio package caused all this mess. I did `sudo apt autoremove texstudio` in recovery mode. After that I reboot from the terminal and I still get black screen. If I select a specific kernel, I get 90s delay with `starting job on /dev/disk/...` followed by a long list of `[ OK ]` and 

 `Timed out waiting for device dev-disk...`, `Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/...`, `Dependency failed for Swap`

Comment: @kedarps it seems to be trying to mount your disk but unable to find it with that UUID. Can you post the the contents of your /etc/fstab file and the results of running the command blkid

Comment: @kingmilo See Update 3. I have mentioned the contents of `/etc/fstab` and results of `blkid`. The UUIDs in both entries do match! But if you see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKSKp.jpg), the `Timed out waiting for device` error ID does not match with `/dev/sda1`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @kedarps Ok, so it doesn't match with sda1 but it DOES match with your swap partition/UUID so it's basically telling you that it cannot mount your swap partition. You can live without your swap partition for now, so comment out the line to mount your swap partition in your /etc/fstab with a # and save and reboot, let's see what it does.

Comment: @kingmilo OK I did that. But now I can't get into GRUB by hitting the right `Shift` key and I just see a black screen :(

Comment: @kedarps what happens if you just try to boot normally not in safe mode? Does it even try to boot, if so, what errors do you see?

Comment: @kedarps if you are still just getting a blank screen then I would suggest doing a grub2 reinstall/repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing scroll down to "Fixing a broken system" By doing this we will just ensure grub has all the right UUID's and information it needs to boot. Getting a blank grub screen is problematic and should be dealt with first and foremost. Give it a go and report back :)

Comment: @kingmilo After the BIOS screen I just see a blank black screen. No errors, nothing. I waited for a good 10 mins to see if anything happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69610/discussion-between-kingmilo-and-kedarps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `apt-get -f install` removed the **ubuntu-desktop** package from your system which is why you are booting to the terminal. You need to install the **ubuntu-desktop** package again to boot to desktop:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`